# Simplecv & shell input

Tags: shell, input, simplecv

I'm developing an app using SimpleCV and I want to use shell while this application runs, to input commands. I'm using Python and since this SimpleCV is a running thread, how am I gonna wait for key events?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at some of the examples using GTK(https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/tree/develop/SimpleCV/examples).  We don't have the shell setup to handle async events.  You can look at the Display class and see how we extended pygame to try and build your own version of it.

It would very well be possible because we are using ipython and they use kernels, you can attach multiple shells/processes to a single kernel. My recommendation would be to do it this way and have your GUI application talk to the same kernel that way variables/objects share the same namespace.